# React - upload a video with youtube data API

Tags: reactjs, youtube-data-api, video-upload

I'm trying to upload a video on youtube in my react app using Youtube Data API, but the documentation is a mess.
Is there an example with the javascript SDK somewhere or I have to implement all the API calls one by one (not so simple if you want resumable uploads...)?